# Passing template function and overload as function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

Short version: Is it possible to mix template functions and overloads when passing a function pointer as an argument to another function?

Details: I'm using `std::search` inside a template function and I'd like to control which function to use for the comparison based on the type of the template, e.g. use a function calling `strcmp` for `char*` and the `operator==` for the other types.

So far I'm using a template functor, specialized for `char*` like this:

```
Comparator<T> comparator;
std::search(....., comparator);
```

That said, there is no such thing as template specializations for template functions, as they would be simple overloads. So, am I stuck to the functor in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no *partial* specializations for function templates. But I think you might have a bigger misunderstanding: "Is is possible to mix template functions and overloads when passing a function pointer ..." Overload resolution happens when the function pointer is created. There is no mix anymore, once the function pointer has been created.

That said, what you appear to want is a *policy*. Hard to google that when you don't know the name, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with full template specialization:

```
#include <string.h>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// template function "MyComperator"
template<class T>
bool MyComperator( T a, T b ) {
    return a < b;
}
// full template specialization for function "MyComperator" with type "char*"
template<>
bool MyComperator<char*>( char *a, char *b ) {
    return strcmp( a, b ) < 0;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back( 3 );
    v1.push_back( 2 );
    v1.push_back( 1 );
    std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end(), &MyComperator<int> );

    std::vector<char*> v2;
    v2.push_back( "C" );
    v2.push_back( "B" );
    v2.push_back( "A" );
    std::sort( v2.begin(), v2.end(), &MyComperator<char*> );

    return 0;
}
```